# How can I find a number in a string using Flex?

Tags: string, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I want to replace a number with a character at runtime like this:

Input:

`ask 1234 question`

Result:

`ask * question`

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Use a Regex to match a number and then do a string replace. Something along the lines of:

```
var str:String = "ask 1234 question"; // your string
var pattern:RegExp = /\d+/ ; // a regular expression that matches numbers
trace(str.replace(pattern, "*"));
```

Look up the flex 3.0 documentation for both String and Regex. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [regular expression](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/RegExp.html).